# Question regarding Linux LSB init script directives

Tags: debian, init.d, lsb

I'm making some init scripts to start some system services that require other services to have started in order to start successfully. For instance, one service requires that `xenstored` be running before it can start.

If I understand correctly, LSB init scripts have the following directives:

```
# Required-Start:
# Should-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Stop:
```

My question is, would it be sufficient to simply put `xenstored` after `Required-Start:` and what is the difference between `Required` and `Should`? Additionally, Does Debian 5 honor these directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and use all those directives for forward compatibility (dependency-based booting), but they will not be used by Debian 5 (lenny). They are used beginning in Debian 6 (squeeze).

In lenny, you should just use:

```
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
```

And then when you install your init.d script do:

```
update-rc.d my-init-script defaults 25
```

Where 25 is greater than the number Y associated with xenstored in /etc/rc[2-5].d/Yxenstored

In Debian Squeeze, assuming xenstored "provides" xenstored:

```
# Required-Start: xenstored
```

For futher reading run:

```
man insserv
```

Comment: Thanks!! Hopefully this shows up in Debian backports as well.

Comment: @Tim: insserv is available on Lenny but since not all init scripts may have the necessary tags for it, installing it might break your system.